# Bootstrap toggle menu uncollapse after I choose a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a difficulties to make my navbar-collapse-toggle on mobile views uncollapse after a choose a link to go.

I actually never saw that, but a client just asked me to do it. Looked in many places but cannot find it.

You can check it at

http://www.neevasoft.com/docasnovo

Any thoughts?

My HTML:

```
<header id="header" class="navbar-fixed-top main-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <!-- Logo start -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
                        <img class="img-responsive"  src="images\logo.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>   

                </div><!--/ Logo end -->

                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse clearfix" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">A Empresa</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#historia">História</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Participações</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Renovada</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contato</a></li>
                        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#acervo">Acervo</a></li>
                        <!--li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li-->
                    </ul>
                </nav><!--/ Navigation end -->

            </div><!--/ Col end -->
        </div><!--/ Row end -->
    </div><!--/ Container end -->
</header><!--/ Header end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps toggle the collapse class on link click event when you check before if you're on a mobile size or not.

Something like this :

```
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 767){ // check if you're on mobile version
      $(".navbar-nav a").click(function(){
        $('.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I haven't test it but I think you get the logic of it.

Comment: I understand the logic, but I just want to hide the collapse after It toggles, collapses and I click on a anchor.

I've tryed what Thomas Antunes suggested, but still no luck...

Tryed yours aswell btw.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method for dynamic collapse:

```
$(".navbar-nav a").click(function(){
    $('.collapse').collapse("hide");
});
```